# Docker images which can handle multiple requests at the same time

Tags: linux, docker, parallel-processing, bytestream

Unfortunately, I'm not really familiar with Linux and Docker. But maybe someone from you can help me.

I need a lightweight Docker image that can do multiple byte stream conversions (e.g. encoding, encryption, compression, ...) in parallel. The process should be called several times outside of the image (e.g. from another image). If I understand it correctly, I need some kind of server that receives and processes the requests.

How do you implement this and how would the program then be called?

Many Thanks

Comment: Essentially any HTTP-processing framework in any language can do this.  Or, if you have a serial process already and the "in parallel" is the problem, you can often launch multiple copies of the container to do more work at the same time.

Comment: can you write demo code that `do single byte stream conversion`, and why do you think doing it in parallel is a problem?

Comment: @LeiYang Let's say I want FFmpeg running in the cloud. And I would like to have an existing video recoded in the Docker container. Since an instance is not fully utilized (limitations in the client), an instance can process several videos in parallel. I would like to have a Docker that does not have long start-up times so that the instances can be scaled relatively quickly.

Comment: My UseCase is a bit more complex, but goes in that direction. I had already thought of a web server as a communicator - but it should be ready quickly. My problem is that I don't have a solid basic knowledge of server infrastructure with Linux, Docker, Kubernetes and Co. And so far I have only deployed on Java, PHP and Node servers. And since there are so many options, I am looking for a rough guide.

Comment: @DavidMaze Which framework would you recommend if byte streams are to be handled, these are to be passed on to programs in the system and if the startup time is also important?

Comment: are you familiar with python? i searched and found some python wrapper, please check https://pypi.org/project/pytranscoder-ffmpeg/

Comment: If it makes sense, I would look into Python. But how would I have to set up a system for python so that I can call a python script from outside?